# Перемещение элементов массива на бинарное дерево

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите пожалуйста, стоит задача сформировать минимальное пирамидальное дерево для поиска на нем определенного элемента (уровня на котором он находится в дереве и позиции на этом уровне). Алгоритм стоит следующий:
1. Сформировать последовательность случайных чисел (без повторений);
2. Занести их в массив;
3. Массив отсортировать по возрастанию (дабы легче было переносить его на дерево и не пришлось сортировать само дерево);
4. Упорядоченный массив перенести на дерево по принципу (в корне стоит a[0] - минимальный элемент, потомки корня - левый a[1], правый a[2], потомки потомков корня слево-направо т.е. a[3] a[4] и тд.
5. Пользователь вводит число и программа ищет это число в дереве, если оно есть то программы пишет уровень и позицию где находится число. 
Так вот, с первыми тремя пунктами проблем нет, а вот дальше я не понимаю как записать в виде программы вышесказанное. Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Заранее спасибо.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

//структура узла дерева
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(int v): value(v), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};

//создание массива случайных (неповторяющихся) целых чисел
void create_array(int*& a, int size)
{
    a = new int [size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        swap(a[i], a[rand() % size]);
    }
}

//вывод массива
void print_array(int *a, int size)
{
    cout << "\nМассив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//сортировка массива методом выбора

void sort_array(int* a, int size)
{
    int min_tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        min_tmp = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] < a[min_tmp]) {min_tmp = j;}
        }
        swap(a[i], a[min_tmp]);
    }
}
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int n = 58;
    int *arr;
    create_array(arr, n);
    print_array(arr, n);
    sort_array(arr, n);
    print_array(arr, n);
    std::vector<Node *> a;
    int i = 1;
    Node *root = new Node(arr[0]);
    a.push_back(root);
    while (i < n)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j += 2)
        {
            Node *c = a[j];
            a.erase(a.begin() + j);
            a.insert(a.begin() + j, new Node(arr[i++]));
            c->left = a[j];
            if (i == n) break;
            a.insert(a.begin() + j + 1, new Node(arr[i++]));
            c->right = a[j + 1];
        }
    }
    a.clear();
    system("pause");
}
```

А как теперь искать число?

Comment: вам нужен видимо обход в ширину. 
Создаёте корень дерева. Дальше заводите счётчик, в котором лежит текущий индекс элемента в массиве для добавления (начинается с единицы, так как корневой элемент создан с arr[0]). Дальше кладёте всех потомков текущего уровня в список, проходите по списку и для каждого потомка выставляете значение (если массив не кончился). Если все узлы из списка обработаны, формируете новый список следующего уровня и так далее пока массив не кончится. Правда дерево не будет деревом поиска.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, я переписал немножко ваш main (мне было лень с русскими буквами возиться и `system("pause")` мне нужен). Вам осталось только сделать действительно массив из случайных не повторяющихся чисел. А ещё мне кажется что преподаватель от вас хотел бинарное дерево поиска, коим то дерево которое вы строите не является. Сортировка массива вас не спасёт.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

//структура узла дерева
struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(int v): value(v), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};

struct SearchResult{
    int level;
    int position;
    SearchResult():level{-1},position{-1}{}     //invalid object
    SearchResult(int lvl, int pos):level{lvl},position{pos}{}
    bool isValid() const{
        return position != -1;
    }
};

//создание массива случайных (неповторяющихся) целых чисел
void create_array(int*& a, int size)
{
    a = new int [size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        swap(a[i], a[rand() % size]);
    }
}

//вывод массива
void print_array(int *a, int size)
{
    cout << "\nArray: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//сортировка массива методом выбора

void sort_array(int* a, int size)
{
    int min_tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        min_tmp = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] < a[min_tmp]) {min_tmp = j;}
        }
        swap(a[i], a[min_tmp]);
    }
}
//поиск. обход в глубину
//обход в глубину можно не делать с помощью рекурсии, вместо неё можно
//использовать стэк. Попробуйте кстати в качестве упражнения. Вообще любую
//(если я не путаю) рекурсию можно переписать на использование стэка.
SearchResult find_recursive(Node* cur, int lvl, int pos, int number){
    if (!cur){
        return {};
    }
    if (cur){
        if (cur->value == number){
            return SearchResult(lvl, pos);
        }
        SearchResult left = find_recursive(cur->left, lvl+1, pos*2, number);
        if (left.isValid()){
            return left;
        };
        SearchResult right = find_recursive(cur->right, lvl+1, pos*2+1, number);
        if (right.isValid()){
            return right;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
//запуск поиска в дереве
SearchResult find_in_tree(Node* root, int number){
    return find_recursive(root, 0, 0, number);
}

//создание дерева из массива
//обход в ширину (для этого используется очередь, можно почитать
//в википедии про алгоритмы на графах и обходы в ширину/в глубину)

Node* fill_tree(int* a, int size){
    Node* ret = new Node(a[0]);
    int curIdx = 1;
    queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(ret);
    while (curIdx < size){
        Node* cur = q.front();
        q.pop();
        cur->left = new Node(a[curIdx]);
        curIdx++;
        if (curIdx >= size){
            break;
        }
        cur->right = new Node(a[curIdx]);
        curIdx++;
        q.push(cur->left);
        q.push(cur->right);
    }
    return ret;
}
//вывод дерева, обходом в ширину
void print_tree(Node* root){
    std::cout << "Tree: ";
    if (!root){
        std::cout << " empty or null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(root);

    while (!q.empty()){
        Node* cur = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (cur){
            std::cout << " " << cur->value;
            q.push(cur->left);
            q.push(cur->right);
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
//удаление дерева.
//Внимание!!!
//Указатель передаётся по ссылке, чтобы обнулить его после удаления,
//чтобы изменения указателя были видны снаружи функции
void delete_tree(Node*& root){
    if (!root){
        return;
    }
    delete_tree(root->left);
    delete_tree(root->right);
    delete root;
    root = nullptr;
    return;
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    int n = 58;
    int *arr;
    create_array(arr, n);
    print_array(arr, n);
    sort_array(arr, n);
    print_array(arr, n);
    Node* root = fill_tree(arr, n);
    print_tree(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+= 2){
        SearchResult r = find_in_tree(root, i);
        if (r.isValid()){
            std::cout << i << " finded. lvl:" << r.level << " pos:" << r.position << std::endl;
        }else{
            std::cout << i << " do not finded in tree" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    delete_tree(root);
    print_tree(root);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Hello world

Array: 42 5 20 8 30 7 4 49 18 47 22 16 2 32 44 28 23 6 36 43 12 27 38 26 50 3 10 34 57 24 54 39 40 55 33 11 21 29 1 19 52 48 25 58 37 31 53 56 14 46 41 35 51 13 9 45 17 15 

Array: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 
Tree:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58
0 do not finded in tree
2 finded. lvl:1 pos:0
4 finded. lvl:2 pos:0
6 finded. lvl:2 pos:2
8 finded. lvl:3 pos:0
10 finded. lvl:3 pos:2
12 finded. lvl:3 pos:4
14 finded. lvl:3 pos:6
16 finded. lvl:4 pos:0
18 finded. lvl:4 pos:2
20 finded. lvl:4 pos:4
22 finded. lvl:4 pos:6
24 finded. lvl:4 pos:8
26 finded. lvl:4 pos:10
28 finded. lvl:4 pos:12
30 finded. lvl:4 pos:14
32 finded. lvl:5 pos:0
34 finded. lvl:5 pos:2
36 finded. lvl:5 pos:4
38 finded. lvl:5 pos:6
40 finded. lvl:5 pos:8
42 finded. lvl:5 pos:10
44 finded. lvl:5 pos:12
46 finded. lvl:5 pos:14
48 finded. lvl:5 pos:16
50 finded. lvl:5 pos:18
52 finded. lvl:5 pos:20
54 finded. lvl:5 pos:22
56 finded. lvl:5 pos:24
58 finded. lvl:5 pos:26
60 do not finded in tree
62 do not finded in tree
64 do not finded in tree
66 do not finded in tree
68 do not finded in tree
70 do not finded in tree
72 do not finded in tree
74 do not finded in tree
76 do not finded in tree
78 do not finded in tree
80 do not finded in tree
82 do not finded in tree
84 do not finded in tree
86 do not finded in tree
88 do not finded in tree
90 do not finded in tree
92 do not finded in tree
94 do not finded in tree
96 do not finded in tree
98 do not finded in tree
Tree:  empty or null
```